# How to inherit class A from B while inheriting B from A?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-inheritance

So I have 2 classes namely `book` and `mainscreen`, where `book` is publically inherited from `mainscreen`.

Now I want to use public member functions of class book via member functions of mainscreen.

Here is my code:

```
class book;

class mainscreen:virtual public book
{
  protected:
    int logged;

  public:
    void printmenu();
    void printhead();
    void auth();
    void logout();
    mainscreen();
};

class book:public mainscreen
{
  private: 
    int bookno, 
        days,
        late_days;
    long double price;

    float fine_calc(int a,float b)  // a -> late days , b -> fine per day
    { 
    return a*b;
    }

  public: 
    book();   //const
    void input();
    void display();
    void update();
};
```

The calling part :-

```
     void mainscreen::printmenu(){
     int i;
     printhead();
     cout<<"\n\n\t  Choose a Number to perform the corresponding task \n";
     cout<<"\n1.Enter a new Book ";
     cout<<"\n2.Issue a Book ";
     cout<<"\n3.Return a book" ;
     cout<<"\n4.Update Information for a book ";
     cout<<"\n5.Information About books ";
     cout<<"\n6.Logout ";

     cout<<"\nEnter your choice: ";
     cin>>i;

     menuhandler(i);

     }

     void mainscreen::menuhandler(int choice){  //the no of choice selected

     switch(choice)
     {
     case 1:        printhead();
        input();

     case 2:        printhead();
        issuebook();         

     case 3:        printhead();
        returnbook();              

     case 4:        printhead();
        update();

     case 5:        printhead();
        display();

     case 6:        logout();                     

     default:
        cout<<"Invalid Choice! Press Return to Try again. ";
        getch();
        printmenu();                        // Reset to menu



     }


     }
```

When I try to use public member functions of class `book` in a member function of `mainscreen`, I get the following error: *call to undefined function*.

Comment: the fact that you can do this does not mean it is a good idea! There is a good reason why c# and java dont allow this. Please consider redesign

Comment: Inheritance is supposed to model *is-a* relationships. But a book is not a main screen, and neither is a main screen a book. Inheritance is the wrong tool for the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: That's simply not possible! What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Inheritance models an *is-a* relationship. If a `book` is a `mainscreen` and the other way around, then they are one class. If that does not answer your question, then you need to explain better what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: What error do you get on which line of your code (which I presume you haven't shown us since this is the declaration not the attempt at afunction call)

Comment: circular inheritance? Definitively is not a good idea

Comment: In what world `A` _is-a_ `B` and `B` _is-a_ `A`?

Comment: I am using the above code for my school C++ project , not for production level .. How to do this ? .. main screen is like universal class for my program .. it controls what displays on screen .. so i should be to use function of other classes to know what to display

Comment: Which compiler allows this `class book; class mainscreen:virtual public book`?? It is ill-formed as per [class.derived]/2 "The type denoted by a *base-type-specifier* shall be a class type that is not an incompletely defined class" (I'm inclined to say *throw that compiler away*)

Comment: Right: my father is my son.

Comment: Just because it's homework doesn't mean you should do it wrong.

Comment: This isn't even your real code, since `mainscreen::menuhandler()` does not appear in either class definition. Using recursive function calls as an alternative to `goto` is a really bad idea. `fine_calc()` doesn't use any member data, and should be a standalone function. Adding a `//const` comment does not make a member function `const`, and this would be rather odd behavior for a constructor anyway. The attempted inheritance relationship is bizarre, as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have:

- identified two entities (classes): `Book` and `MainScreen`
- and then you identified common behavior and attributes of these classes

Yet you came with very wrong conclusion, that these classes should inherit from each other (i.e. provide some behavior / attributes to each other). What you should do instead is create a third class that these classes will inherit (whatever they are meant to have in common) from.

A possible interface-based approach could be for example:

```
class Displayable {
public:
    virtual void display();
};

class Book : public Displayable {
    ...
};

class MainScreen : public Displayable {
    ...
};
```